# Injecting custom IDbCommand in NHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, transient, dbcommand

We use Fluent `NHibernate` with SQL server 2008. I need `NHibernate` to use my custom `DbCommand` class (inherited from `IDbCommand`). In this custom `DbCommand` class, I want to handle transient errors (e.g. any transient network errors etc...) and retry the same command certain number of times before failing.

I know, Microsoft provides Transient Fault handling block (with methods like `SqlConnectionExtensions`.OpenWithRetry and similar method for retriable `ExecuteNonQuery`)  for handling transient errors but, I guess it is specific to Windows Azure platform.

Let me know if `NHibernate` provides any mechanism for injecting custom behaviours.